# Method to Return List of Instances Without Self

Tags: python, django, methods, instance

I am frequently running an operation to determine a list of "live" instances of a class. To determine if an instance is live, it is testing against the is_live method of my current class -- please see below.

```
class Game(models.Model):

    def is_live(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        now.astimezone(timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
        if self.time is not None and now < self.time:
            return True
        if self.time is None:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Instead of having to run this loop in all of my views, I would love to create another method to run that returned a list of all live instances. However, to do so I wouldn't need the use of self and am getting an error every time I try to do so. Any ideas how to complete this. The loop would be something like the below

```
def live_game_list():
    live_game_list = [] 
    for game in Game.objects.all():
          if game.is_live == True: 
                live_game_list.append(game)
    return live_game_list
```

Then I would just be able to call Game.live_game_list() and get a list of all games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the class method as static using the `@staticmethod` decorator.  You then don't need to pass `self` to the function.  Rather than use `Game` directly within the function, why don't you pass the game objects as a parameter to the function.  I've used a conditional list comprehension to generate the result which will be more efficient than using `append`.

```
@staticmethod
def live_game_list(game_objects):
    return [game for game in game_objects.all() if game.is_live]
```

Comment: what do I set game_objects to be? just Game.objects.all()?

Comment: You can set it to whatever container you have to hold your games.  The method described by @Karin below is one such solution (not sure why she was downvoted).  The `.all()` method was to be consistent with your original code, but I don't see why it is necessary.  If the container is a list of game objects, then you can simply iterate through it via `[game for game in game_objects if game.is_live]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will need to keep track of all `Game` instances outside of the individual instances themselves. You can do this anywhere, but one option is to have a class-level list:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    all_game_instances = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Game, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.all_game_instances.append(self)  # accesses class attribute list

    @classmethod
    def live_game_list(cls):
        return [game for game in cls.all_game_instances if game.is_live()]

    def is_live(self):
        ...
```

Then you can access the list of games with `Game.live_game_list()`.